# autocomplete constructor in phpstorm

Tags: class, autocomplete, phpstorm

Is there a way for PhpStorm to autocomplete a constructor as soon as I start a new class?  (I've seen a video where this can be done in Netbeans, for example)

Comment: 1) **Code | Override Methods...** (Ctrl+O) 2) Select `__construct` there. **Alternatively:** customize `PHP Class` template in "Settings | File Templates" (will **only** be used when creating new class in new file via "File | New | PHP Class")

Comment: The first option is what I'm looking for.  However, it's currently "greyed out".  Any thoughts how I might access it?

Comment: It is enabled only when you (cursor, actually) are inside the class.

Comment: As I understand you have the answer: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/443455

Comment: That was in fact the exact solution that I was looking for.  If it was bad form to cross-post, I do apologize; however, if the link can help a future user, then at least it can help someone else...

Comment: There was nothing wrong, I just wanted to confirm.

Comment: @LazyOne could you post your comment as an answer so that this question can be marked 'answered'?

Answer (score 0):

You bet!  Just follow the link...

http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/443455

Comment: The suggestion there seems pretty lame.... I think there are better ways in PHPStorm, sadly,  one needs to click the link to learn about the limited suggestion you give. -1 as this answer is not helpful.